# Sharepoint 2010 Programming, How to start (Licencing)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I had a question: I wanted to begin programming in `Sharepoint` and I thought I could get some pointers in which of Sharepoint 2010 Foundation, Sharepoint 2010 Client... etc to download so I can learn to program for `Sharepoint`.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install Sharepoint 2010 foundation you should read this post:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869(v=office.14).aspx

It worked properly to me

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest you to create your own SharePoint trial site on O365, so that you don't have to install on Premises. Then, do video tutorials from which you can learn quickly. After you are comfortable, you can install SharePoint on Premises.

Comment: Is the office 365 trial site access still exists?  if yes, can anyone point the URL for getting access to the O 365 SharePoint site collection.

Answer (score 0):

At this date you are probably better off with SharePoint 2013 but it doesn't really matter.

Install SharePoint 2010 foundation or 2013 foundation from WPI (Web Platform Installer). Also install Visual Studio from WPI if you dont already have it.

Use a Server Os, running SharePoint in Windows 7 is possible but I wouldn't recommend it for beginners. You must have a 64-bit enterprise or ultimate version of win 7 in such case. If you insist on win7 here is the official documentation on how to do this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sharepoint/ee554869(v=office.14)

Youtube is your friend when it commes to how to startup with SharePoint development. Browse, Look, Read.

Good luck

Comment: Yeah, I would also recommend you do it on a virtual machine.

Comment: If you'll look to the SharePoint 2013 side, it is not really necessary install SharePoint environment, you can develop SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2013 apps just using Visual Studio and SharePoint developer tools. Look at this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2012/08/16/installing-office-2013-and-sharepoint-2013-developer-tools-preview-for-visual-studio-2012-rtm.aspx

Comment: @AntonKhritonenkov Using the online versions and apps is an awful way of learning SharePoint

Comment: For fast start, just to see what is SharePoint and how to use it. It is the best way. For deeper learning of course it is better to have your own server. But in fact the situation is going to such type of development, App based, web service based. Where you can develop application without deployment farm solutions to the farm.

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to install SharePoint 2010, first install it in your virtual machine I would recommend to use first chapter of the book "Real World SharePoint 2010: Indispensable Experiences from 22 MVPs". It contains information about how to install SharePoint 2010.

Microsoft provides all related softwares like Windows Server, SharePoint Server, Sql Server free for trial purposes for a period of 180 days. The only thing where you have to invest is in a good hardware.
You may download evaluation version of sp2010 from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sharepoint-server-2010

To create virtual machine you might want to download VMware Player which is a virtualization software package supplied free of charge by VMware, Inc.

If you don't want to spend time on installing SharePoint you may use something like cloudshare or microsofts own windows azure.

There are plenty of videos on YouTube on SharePoint which help you understand basics of SharePoint 2010 and to begin programming on SharePoint 2010.

Regards,

Hiren Gondhiya